# Any Suggestion!! How to retrieve the old value for a column with trigger?

Tags: db2

How can we retrieve the old stored value for the column as though again if if it is updated to null ? Then how we can update the old value itself using trigger

Comment: Learn now to ask a good question.  If English is not your first language, get help with the grammar to make sure that the question is clear. Do not assume that people know what you mean.  Explain your environment, show your code, show what you tried, show what kind of trigger you are using etc.   Otherwise your question will get closed , without any answer.

Comment: You may have an access to the old state of updated row with the `REFERENCING OLD AS correlation-name` clause of `BEFORE UPATE` ... `FOR EACH ROW` trigger. Edit the question with your attempt. Refer to the [CREATE TRIGGER statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-trigger).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to do, but here is one interpretation. Assuming a table like:

```
db2 "create table t (x int not null primary key, y int)"
```

A trigger like:

```
create or replace trigger <trigname>
before update of y on t
referencing new as n old as o
for each row
    when (n.y is null)
            set n.y = o.y @
```

may be what you are looking for